# How to access NSArray in another View

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have some problems with my XML parser, written in obj-c.
The parser itself is fine but I cant access the result Array in the DetailView.

I need the values of the array created by the Parser Class in my Master and DetailViewController.

In MasterViewController I do this:

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TouchXML.h"
#import "Parser.h"

@class Parser;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController{
    Parser *theParser;
    }
```

MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    theParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
    [theParser startParser:xmlPath]; //Now the parser runs and parses all needed values into arrays
}
```

Then I push on click the DetailView and I want to access the values there too.

UniViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Parser.h"

@interface UniViewController : UITableViewController{

    Parser *theParser;
}
```

UniViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSLog(@"Name: %@",[[theParser.listArray objectAtIndex: 0]valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Here I want to access the the Array from the parser but I always get the value (null) ?
In the debugger I saw that theParser has 0x0000 which cant be right...
After I do theParser = [[Parser alloc] init]; here, it has an hex value but I still get the (null).

How can I access the Array values from the DetailView?

Would be really nice if someone could explain me the problem here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your detail view has to have a pointer to the array that your MasterView creates (via the parser), try this:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    aParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
    [aParser startParser:xmlPath];
    myUniView.theParser = aParser; //myUniView is just the detail view you're pushing
```

and then after this you can push your detail view.

Comment: How can I do this with a normal class, not a view? Im trying to access my Array in the Annotation Class for the MapView. In the MasterViewController... before I push the DetailView, I do:     Annotation *Anno = [[Annotation alloc] init];   
Anno.theParser = theParser; 
But I cant access the Array in the Annotation.m class ?

Comment: is the parser already allocated when you assign it to the Annotation? Also are you just using one parser throughout the application? If so you can consider making your parser class a singleton so that you can reach it from any class

Comment: Is Annotation *Anno = [[Annotation alloc] init]; right? I do this before Anno.theParser = theParser;... I will have a look at singletons

Comment: yes take a look at them, and no, what I mean is: are you performing somewhere in your code theParser = [[Parser alloc] init]; before assigning it to you annotation??

Comment: I do theParser = [[Parser alloc] init]; in viewDidLoad in MasterViewController. Just cant find the problem... I do the same things than before...

Comment: the question is too broad, you have to show me some code. Is the Annotation object anno you create the same as the one in your map view, it won't work if you're initializing a different instance in you mapView..

Comment: thanks for your help, it works now. I put Annotation *Anno = [[Annotation alloc]init]; and Anno.theParser = theParser; in DetailView and did only #import "Annotation.h" ... and it works.